# Coq proof automation not working like I expect

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm currently working on RedBlack from software foundations...I'm up to "ins_is_redblack" (you can find it here https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/vfa-current/Redblack.html).

I'm struggling to figure out why my match goal isn't working. The target has lots of invocations, and I'm supposed to automate the solution. Here are two representative examples:

```
nearly_redblack
  match c with
  | Red =>
      match t1 with
      | E =>
          match t2 with
          | T Red b y vy c0 =>
              T Red (T Black t1 k0 v0 b) y vy (T Black c0 k v E)
          | _ => T Black (T c t1 k0 v0 t2) k v E
          end
      | T Red a x0 vx0 b =>
          T Red (T Black a x0 vx0 b) k0 v0 (T Black t2 k v E)
      | T Black _ _ _ _ =>
          match t2 with
          | T Red b0 y vy c0 =>
              T Red (T Black t1 k0 v0 b0) y vy (T Black c0 k v E)
          | _ => T Black (T c t1 k0 v0 t2) k v E
          end
      end
  | Black => T Black (T c t1 k0 v0 t2) k v E
  end 1
```

and

```
nearly_redblack
  (if ltb k x then balance Black s1 k v (ins x vx s2) else T Black s1 x vx s2)
  (S n0)
```

I'm trying to build up my automation incrementally, but got stuck pretty quickly

```
repeat match goal with
 (* doesn't work *)
 | |- nearly_redblack (match ?c with Red => _ | Black => _ end) _ => destruct c
 (* works *)
 | |- nearly_redblack (T _ _ _ _ _) 1  => constructor
 (* works *)
 | |- is_redblack E Black 0 => constructor
 (* doesn't work *)
 | |- match ?c with Red => _ | Black => _ end => destruct c
 (* doesn't work *)
 | |- nearly_redblack (if ltb ?k ?x then _ else _) _ => bdestruct (ltb k x); try omega
end.
```

I'm a bit stuck as to why this isn't working...it seems to match the other uses of automation in the file, but I don't really have a good mental model of how the match goal works. Hopefully someone here can help me figure out what is going on. Coq's proof automation seems very powerful but the syntax is ah...

Comment: There is an Ltac debugger you can turn on with `Set Ltac Debug.`. I suggest you run the tactic with `repeat` once to get to the point where the automation fails, and then turn on debugging to step through the tactic.